# Can we replace the condition $d(E_1,E_2)>0$ with $E_1\cap{E_2}=\emptyset$ in an property of outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can we replace the condition $d(E_1,E_2)>0$ with $E_1\cap{E_2}=\emptyset$ in "If $E=E_1\cup{E_2}$,and $d(E_1,E_2)>0$,then $m_\star(E)=m_\star(E_1)+m_\star(E_2)$."? Obviously,$E_1\cap{E_2}=\emptyset$ can not imply $d(E_1,E_2)>0$.I think we can't replace the condition,but I can't find a counter-example. Can you give me a counter-example?

Comment: This property is needed to ensure that the (outer) measure is *metric*, which in turn implies that Borel sets are measurable. This is not trivial and is a theorem by Caratheodory. Look for the keywords "Caratheodory's criterion" in the net or in some book on geometric measure theory, such as Evans-Gariepy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counterexample is (necessarily) a nonmeasurable set. Try working with Vitali sets.